# Writing in parallel in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write data to azure blob storage by splitting the data into multiple parts so that each can be written to different azure blob storage accounts. I see the below loop runs in sequence. Is there a way to parallelize the write?

```
    var accounts = Array("acct1", "acct2", "acct3", "acct4")

    val numSplits =  Array.fill(4)(0.25)
    val splitDf = df.randomSplit(numSplits)

    val batchCt=0

    splitDf.foreach { ds =>

        val acct = accounts(batchCt)
        val outputFolder = "wasb://test@"+acct+".blob.core.windows.net/json/hourly/%1$tY/%1$tm/%1$td/%1$tH/"
        val outputFile = String.format(outputFolder, currentTime) 
        ds.write.json(outputFile)
        batchCt = batchCt + 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [mapPartitionsWithIndex](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@mapPartitionsWithIndex[U](f:(Int,Iterator[T])=>Iterator[U],preservesPartitioning:Boolean)(implicitevidence$9:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U]) to achieve your goal. The code will look like this (I didn't try this with DataFrames, only with RDD's but they can be converted to each other freely):

```
var accounts = Array("acct1", "acct2", "acct3", "acct4")

val rdd =  sc.parallelize(Array.fill(4)(1)) // dummy data
// We create 4 partitions to write in 4 parallel streams 
// (assuming you have 4 executors)
val splitRdd = rdd.repartition(4).mapPartitionsWithIndex{
    case (ind, vals) =>
        // Here we use the partition number to pick the account
        val acct = accounts(ind) 
        val outputFolder = "wasb://test@"+acct+".blob.core.windows.net/json/hourly/%1$tY/%1$tm/%1$td/%1$tH/"
        vals.foreach{
            v => 
            // ...
            // do the write of value v
        }
}
```

Please pay attention to how the `.repartition` is actually performed, it is very easy to end up with unevenly spread partitions.

Comment: The problem is I don't have access to the DataFrameWriter from inside the mapPartitionsWithIndex to write to Azure blob storage. I want to be able to call something like dataframe.write.json(output).  Also, I can't call rdd.saveAsTextFile.

Comment: Ok, I see. In fact I use this approach for writing into Postgres, kind of different thing. I will think about it.